How frequent is usage of string type in FMU model description variables?
I am implementing support for FMU import in my application that is quite low-level and deals with PLCs, and at the moment I am able to work only with booleans, integers and floats. How frequent is usage of string type in FMU variables? For example for string concat operations? So far I have only seen  with integers and floats, and booleans.
Of course, if the standard tells me I have to implement support for strings as well, I will do it, but I think that it is out of scope for the prototyping stage of the project.
I checked model description files in https://github.com/modelica/Reference-FMUs but I didn't find any variables of a string type, only variables that could be converted to either bool or a number type, depending on context. Model name and description do not count, since no operations should be done with them during co-simulation.

String parameters as well as string inputs, outputs are valid variables defined in the FMI standard.
You can find e.g. an example in the Reference FMUs here: https://github.com/modelica/Reference-FMUs/tree/main/Feedthrough
Some simulation tools do not support the String variables at all as they are only intended for numerical simulation with numerical data types.
So they are not fully FMI compliant.
However, I would say that most tools support string parameters, while string inputs/outputs are only supported by a minority of tools.
In FMI 3.0 supporting tools the situation is better, as most of them support binary variables, a concept that is not far away from string variables.
